# type assignment warning when porting code from xc32-gcc to standard gcc

Tags: c, gcc, compiler-warnings

I'm an assignment warning when using gcc compiler

```
warning: assignment makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]
```

the function is very simple

```
char* pShortToBuffer_Parse( char* DisBuff, short value )
{   
    *DisBuff++ = (char) (value >> 8);
    *DisBuff++ = (char) value;  
   return DisBuff;
}
```

and i'm caling it like the following

```
short PacketSize = 0;char* PbufDst;    
PbufDst = pShortToBuffer_Parse( PbufDst, PacketSize);
```

the warning goes away when i don't return the adress of PbufDst

```
pShortToBuffer_Parse( PbufDst, PacketSize);
```

Not sure what i'm missing here, I have this same piece of code working with no problem nor warnings in another projet that uses microchip xc32-gcc compiler

Any idea guys ?

Comment: That sounds like a declaration of `pShortToBuffer_Parse` is not in scope at the point where you call it (maybe try `gcc -Wimplicit` to confirm?). It's hard to tell for sure because your question doesn't include a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The moment the compiler tries to translate

```
PbufDst = pShortToBuffer_Parse( PbufDst, PacketSize);
```

it does not seem to know about `pShortToBuffer_Parse()` yet. In such cases the C Standard defines to assume `int` as return value, resulting in trying to assign this very `int` to `PbufDst` which is a `char*`.

To fix this either place the declaration or definition of `pShortToBuffer_Parse()` in front.

Comment: Very true. Thank you